# How do you apply an "umph" effect when a user clicks on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, templates

Sort of like a little indent whenever a picture is clicked....the image goes "inward" a couple pixels.  And then when the mouse button is off, the picture goes back to normal.  This is like a "depressed" state, like most buttons have.

Ideally, is there a JQuery plugin for this?

Comment: Can you describe the desired effect a little more?

Comment: @Surreal I believe he means the way buttons appear depressed by inverting their borders on mouse-down. I've never heard this completely standard behaviour called "umph" before, it's probably not the best choice of words.

Comment: Most buttons have this depressed, "umph" state when the mouse is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a jQuery plugin for this. The following will bump the element down and to the right two pixels on mouse-down, and move it back to it's original position on mouse-up.

```
$(".my_element").mousedown(function () {
  $(this).animate({ top : '+=2', left : '+=2' });
}).mouseup(function () {
  $(this).animate({ top : '-=2', left : '-=2' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some simple CSS to do this:

```
a:active img {
    margin: 2px -2px -2px 2px;
}
```

The negative margins are there to offset the positive margins to prevent the width and height of the anchor from changing, affecting the surrounding elements. See [this simple jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) to see this working live.